# NameError - undefined local variable - Parsing array from ruby file to haml file

Tags: mysql, ruby, ajax, sinatra, haml

We are using a Mysql database and make use of haml files.

The issue we have now is when we dynamically create a table with data from our mysql database it gives us this error:

```
NameError - undefined local variable or method `allsites' for #<Sinatra::Application:0x00
00000128c980>:
    /home/usr/testsinatra/views/sites.haml:16:in `block in singleton class'
    /home/usr/testsinatra/views/sites.haml:-8:in `instance_eval'
    /home/usr/testsinatra/views/sites.haml:-8:in `singleton class'
    /home/usr/testsinatra/views/sites.haml:-10:in `__tilt_12132720'
```

**The weird thing is that the table is actually created !**

This is the part of the ruby file where we fill our array with mysql data.

```
get '/getsites' do

allsites = con2.query("SELECT * FROM tblSites", :as => :array)



haml :sitesOverzicht, :locals => {:allsites => allsites}
end
```

This is the part where we make our table dynamically:

```
%table{:border => "1px"}
  %tbody
    %h1 All Sites
    -allsites.each do |id,name|
      %tr
        %td
          = id
        %td 
          = name
```

The other strange part is when the page loads, we don't get any error and the table is created when the page loads.
But when we create a new tablerow in another table from another array and store this data with **Ajax**, we get this error for this variable even if we don't do anything.

Comment: What is in allsites after your mysql query?

Comment: In 'allsites' we store an array from the table tblSites, which contains a SiteID and a siteName.  @Sirl33tname

Comment: Oh sorry that I ask that unclear, can you please paste somewhere what the output from `p allsites` exactly is

Comment: In console we get this output: 
`1 Brugge_testbedrijf`    
`2 Oostende `    
`3 Ieper`    
`4 Gent`
this in tableform offcourse => the first column is the ID and the second is the name @Sirl33tname

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find a fix for my own problem !

To make use of our local variable we had to use the "@" sign like this for our Query:

```
@allSites = con2.query("SELECT * FROM tblSites", :as => :array)
```

Afterwards we changed it also in our link to send it to the haml file:

```
haml :sitesOverzicht,:locals => {:allSites => @allSites}
```

Afterwards in our haml file we got the NoMethodException but we found out that we had to make use of the `to_a.each` function to make use of the `"each"` function we allready had like this:

```
 -@allSites.to_a.each do |id,name|

  %tr
    %td
      = id
    %td 
      = name
```

With the `to_a.each` function you say that you will make use of an array as parameter. So `the each` function will loop over an array. If you use `the each` function without saying you are using an array, it will give a nill exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your Answer maybe work but it's not really nice.

Because with @ you define a [Instance variable](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/instancevars.html) probably not what you want. But of course you can do that but then you can remove `:locals => {:allSites => @allSites}`

But in most cases it's better to use locals:

app.rb

```
get "/" do
  allsites = {"1" => "name", "2" => "name 2", "3" => "name3"}
  p allsites
  haml :index, :locals => {:allsites => allsites}
end
```

views/index.haml

```
-allsites.each do |id,name|
    %tr
        %td
            = id
        %td
            = name
```

works fine for me so this indicate that what ever your `con2.query("SELECT * FROM tblSites", :as => :array)` returns it's not exactly what you expected.